# Android JobScheduler onStopJob not getting called

Tags: android

I have implemented a Demo Application for JobScheduler. Below are my Code for MainActivity and JobScheduler Service. OnStopJob is not called even when i press Cancel all task button to cancel All Scheduled Jobs. I am unable to understand it why it is happening. I have also tried returning true from onStopJob.

## MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.jobschedulerdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.job.JobInfo;
import android.app.job.JobScheduler;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private JobScheduler mJobScheduler;
    private Button mScheduleJobButton;
    private Button mCancelAllJobsButton;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mScheduleJobButton = (Button) findViewById( R.id.schedule_job );
        mCancelAllJobsButton = (Button) findViewById( R.id.cancel_all );
        mJobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        mScheduleJobButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                JobInfo.Builder jobBuilder = new JobInfo.Builder(1, new ComponentName(getPackageName(), TestJobService.class.getName()));
                jobBuilder.setPeriodic(3000);
                jobBuilder.setRequiresCharging(true);
                if(mJobScheduler.schedule(jobBuilder.build()) <= 0){
                    Log.i(TAG, "Error in scheduling job");
                }
            }
        });

        mCancelAllJobsButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mJobScheduler.cancelAll();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

## TestJobService.java

```
package com.example.jobschedulerdemo;

import android.app.job.JobParameters;
import android.app.job.JobService;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestJobService extends JobService{
    private static final String TAG = "TestJobService";

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Toast.makeText(TestJobService.this, "Task Running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            jobFinished((JobParameters)msg.obj, false);
            return false;
        }
    });

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onJobStarted : Job Id = " + params.getJobId());
        mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(mHandler, 1, params));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStopJob : Job Id = " + params.getJobId());
        mHandler.removeMessages(1);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**onStopJob(JobParameters params)** is used by the system to cancel pending tasks when a cancel request is received.

You can easily reproduce it by running a Job and cancel it **BEFORE** it ends (before calling jobFinished(...)). It's suppose you put there the required logic to cancel your background task.

3 seconds maybe is too short to make the test. Try with more time.